# plpgsql - add days to timestamp

Tags: timestamp, plpgsql, intervals, dynamic-sql

I'm executing the following sql within a postgress funcation. I'm trying to add number of days to the column rec_cren_dt(timestamp with timezone).

```
      EXECUTE format('insert into archive.%s_ar
           select * from schema.%s
           where rec_cren_dt > ''%s'' + INTERVAL ''%s DAY'';
          ', x, x, mindt, tar_date
        );
```

Which gives me the error

```
ERROR: invalid input syntax for type interval: "2020-05-05 20:52:44.347" LINE 3: where rec_cren_dt > '2020-05-05 20:52:44.347' + I... ^
```

ACtual query that got executed -

```
QUERY: insert into archive.appl_stng_ar select * from fez.appl_stng where rec_cren_dt > '2020-05-05 20:52:44.347' + INTERVAL '1 DAY';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Postgres miss type info for this string. You should to use a explicit cast

```
where rec_cren_dt > ''%s''::timestamp + INTERVAL ''%s DAY'';
```

or better, use `USING` clause

```
EXECUTE format('insert into archive.%s_ar
                select * from schema.%s
                where rec_cren_dt > $1 + INTERVAL ''1 DAY'' * $2',
                x, x)
  USING mindt, tar_date;
```

I see another significant issue - sql injection. You use `%s` placeholder in meaning table name. In this case you should to use `%I`.

With `USING` clause, your statement can be simplified:

```
EXECUTE format('insert into archive.%I'
               ' select * from schema.%I'
               ' where rec_cren_dt > $1', x || '_ar', x)
  USING mindt + (tar_date * interval '1 day');
```

Comment: Works perfectly now. Thanks.